# sqlplus using of sub query

Tags: sql, database

I have 3 tables, and have to find out the applicant number, name and total number of position each applicant applied for.

```
CREATE TABLE    APP (
appNum      varchar2(10)    not null,
appName     varchar2(70),
constraint applicant_Pkey primary key (appNum)
);

CREATE TABLE    POS (
posNum          varchar2(10)    not null,
posStartOfferDt     date        not null,
constraint pos_Pkey primary key (posNum, posStartOfferDt)
);



CREATE TABLE    APPLICATION (
appcnPosNum     varchar2(10)    not null,
appcnPosStOffrDt    date        not null,
appcnAppNum     varchar2(10)    not null,
appcnDt         date,
constraint application_Pkey primary key (appcnPosNum, appcnPosStOffrDt, appcnAppNum),
constraint application_Fkey1 foreign key (appcnPosNum, appcnPosStOffrDt) references     POSITION(posNum, posStartOfferDt),
constraint application_Fkey2 foreign key (appcnAppNum) references APPLICANT(appNum)
);
```

I have tried using sub query, natural join but all not working out for me.

Comment: Which sql version are you using? mySql, MSSQL/T-SQL, Oracle, etc?

Comment: SELECT   a.appNum, a.appName, COUNT(ap.appcnAppNum)
FROM     applicant a left
JOIN     application ap ON a.appNum = ap.appcnAppNum
GROUP BY a.appNum, a.appName

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   appNum, appName, COUNT(*)
FROM     applicant
JOIN     application ON applicant.appNum = application.appcnAppNum
GROUP BY appNum, appName
```